# EF Code First - duration of Context when used in populating model

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, model

I'm migrating a Typed Dataset-based WPF app to use Entity Framework 5 Code First (.Net 4.5).

I currently load up the model with data from the DataSet. Model fields are then bound to XAML DataGrids.  Using a combination of ObservableCollections in the model and domain objects derived from INotifyPropertyChanged, I can get which CRUD operation is going on at the collection and domain object levels and act accordingly:

```
public class DomainObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public DataRowState State;
 ...
} 

public class Model
{
  private ObservableCollection<DomainObject> _family = new ObservableCollection<DomainObject>();

  public Model()
  {
    List<DomainObject> objs = DS.GetObjects();
    foreach ( var obj on objs )
    {
     obj.PropertyChanged += OnObjectChanged;       
     _family.Add(obj);
    }

    _family.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
  }

 void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
 {
  // do stuff against DataSet based on e.Action
  ...
 }

 private void OnObjectChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
 {
   // do stuff against DataSet based on sender's (DomainObject) State property.
   ...
 }
}
```

In my current implementation, I am able to pseudo-batch up the CRUD operations in the dataset before writing them to the database when the user presses a `Save` button, or the DataSet is discarded if Cancel is pressed.

Is it an acceptable pattern for an EF DbContext to use it similar to how I used the DataSet when it is used to populate a model?  It seems like the Context has to stay around for the life of the model if you expect to be able to save object updates.

Thanks for any guidance!
Corey.

Comment: If you are using a Domain object in your system, you should be able to do the following when user clicks on Save button: Fire up a dbcontext(in a using statement), use linq to grab the EF object, perform updates to EF object by reading the Domain object, call SaveChanges on the DbContext.

Comment: This might be a useful link for you http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ado_net/Managing-Entity-Framework-ObjectContext-lifespan-and-scope-in-n-layered-ASP-NET-applications.aspx

Comment: Thanks!  If the domain objects are derived classes, would I then have to write a copy operator for each base class to migrate updates to the EF-held object?

Comment: Yes you can do that. In fact you can make the copy operator virtual, so that derived classes can override when necessary. Personally, I prefer to abstract the logic in a service class instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are asking for is some Undo/Redo implementation using the DbContext, for that check out [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/474279/Implementing-Undo-Redo-feature-for-DbContext-of-En), and as i see you are using WPF so you should try and use [IEditableObject interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject.aspx) for this mechanism. On the other hand the DbContext has to live until you call save changes after any modifications you have made to that context.